# Integration Help: $\sqrt{(x^4 + x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you integrate $\sqrt{(x^4 + x^2)}$?

Comment: Factor out $x^2$, then factor out $|x|$ and you roughly have $f'\cdot f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{x^4+x^2}\,dx&=\int\sqrt{x^2(x^2+1)}\,dx\\
&=\int x\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx\\
&=\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,xdx\\
\end{align}
Let $u=x^2+1$, then $du=2x\,dx$ or $x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}du$. Hence
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{x^4+x^2}\,dx
&=\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,xdx\\
&=\int \sqrt{u}\frac{1}{2}du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int u^{\frac{1}{2}}\,du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+1}u^{\frac{1}{2}+1}+C\\
&=\frac{1}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}}+C\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}+C\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(x^2+1)^3}+C
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't we take $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it now- was just unsure what to substitute in the first place and I've got limits on the integration and it's all positive anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As long as we are considering positive values of $x$, we have
$$\int\sqrt{x^4+x^2}\,dx=\int x\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx\ ,$$
and this is easy to integrate.

Comment: But then would you use parts, substitution or?

Comment: Ella: Put $u = x^2 + 1 \rightarrow du = 2x \,dx \iff \frac{du}{2} = x \,dx$. $$\frac 12\int \sqrt{\underbrace{x^2 + 1}_u} \;\underbrace{2x\,dx}_{du} = \frac 12\int u^{1/2} \,du$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Put $x^2+1=t$ and and notice $2xdx=dt.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that you may write, as David pointed out, the simplification $$\int \sqrt{x^4 + x^2}\space dx = \int x\sqrt{x^2+1}\space dx$$

Now, notice the substitution $u = x^2+1$, $du = 2x\space dx$. So we have $$\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{u}\space du = \frac{1}{2}\int u^{1/2}\space du = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}+C = \frac{1}{3}\sqrt{(x^2+1)^3}+C$$